# RegisterRawInputDevices() is generating ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: c++, windows, raw-input

When my windows application (a game) starts, I register it to receive raw input messages:

```
RAWINPUTDEVICE Rid[2];
Rid[0].usUsagePage  = HID_USAGE_PAGE_GENERIC;     // 0x01
Rid[0].usUsage      = HID_USAGE_GENERIC_MOUSE;    // 0x02
Rid[0].dwFlags      = RIDEV_INPUTSINK;   
Rid[0].hwndTarget   = sMainWindow;                // HWND from created window

Rid[1].usUsagePage  = HID_USAGE_PAGE_GENERIC;     // 0x01
Rid[1].usUsage      = HID_USAGE_GENERIC_KEYBOARD; // 0x06
Rid[1].dwFlags      = RIDEV_INPUTSINK;   
Rid[1].hwndTarget   = sMainWindow;

BOOL result = RegisterRawInputDevices( Rid, 2, sizeof( Rid[0] ) );

if( !result )
{
    EGSystemError( "RegisterRawInputDevices Error: ", GetLastError() );
}
```

This game has been released and many users seem to have no trouble with it, but I have one user who is getting the error message:

```
"RegisterRawInputDevices Error: The system cannot find the file specified"
```

So, the question is- *why* would RegisterRawInputDevices() ever generate a ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND error? I haven't seen any references in the docs that help. Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: The most obvious possibility is that there is either no mouse or no keyboard.

Comment: I had the user send over his DXDiag results. He appears to have a mouse hooked up, and the keyboard actually is listed 3 times in a row. I'm not sure what that means or if it is even unusual. But at least they are connected. I asked him to try disconnecting/reconnecting. Maybe trying a new keyboard would help too :\

Comment: Did you figure out the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Above comment is not correct or spec is not correct

MSDN is reporting https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/ms645600(v=vs.85).aspx

cbSize [in]
Type: UINT
The size, in bytes, of a RAWINPUTDEVICE structure.

Answer (score -1):

The reason why this isn't working is because you are passing only one `RAWINPUTDEVICE` structure for the `sizeof`. It should be like this..

```
sizeof( Rid )
```

not

```
sizeof( Rid[0] )
```

Hope this helps for others since I had a bit of trouble with it also!

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerrawinputdevices `cbSize` should be ***The size, in bytes, of a RAWINPUTDEVICE structure.***